# Clicking noise from the extruder and no filament coming out

Tags: filament, extruder, monoprice-maker-select

When trying to print (using 215 °C for the hotend and 65 °C for the bed) there seems to be a clicking and filament stops extruding.

After much work I have cleaned the nozzle and made sure there are no clogs in the machine. However the filament seems to not extrude. When I get the filament out, there are small cuts/marks on the filament. Please see the attached picture for a better view.

I'm not sure if the marks are causing the issue or if there could be something else going on. Any suggestions on how to fix the extruder to push out filament? Everything was working normally until yesterday after I leveled the print bed.

[image: Filament with marks]

Comment: Which Monoprice do you have, the Select has a whole family of printers (Bowden or direct extruders), also what material are you printing; please [edit]. When you heated up the hotend, you should be able to push filament through by hand when you relieve the force that the extruder exerts on the filament (usually there is a lever). Try to find where the filament gets to and solve it from those observations. Try cutting the filament under a sharp angle when you insert a fresh piece. From the question it is not clear whether the nozzle extrudes filament at all.

Comment: I have the maker select v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of points missing, but I can offer a few suggestions. The re-leveling of the bed could have resulted in the bed now being in a position to block the nozzle. I have done exactly that in the past. A clean glass bed makes for a perfect clog.

The marks on the filament fit the description of a hobbed gear (extruder drive bolt) chewing into the filament, which would move only slightly from being blocked at the nozzle.

Additionally, filament temperature may be a factor, although it's difficult to determine with the information provided.

For a test, consider to use the controls available to you to raise the nozzle/lower the bed. Bring the nozzle up to your normal filament temperature. Execute an extrusion of sufficient length to ensure that the filament will reach and exit the nozzle.

If this does not provide extrusion, raise the temperature five degrees C and make another attempt. It may be necessary to raise the temperature in steps more than one time.

Use undamaged filament in these tests to ensure that the damage does not factor into the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have been printing pla at 215c and the bed temp at 65c. If there is anything else I could provide please let me know.

Comment: The results of my suggested test (paragraph 4) would be useful to better determine a more precise answer.

Comment: @moulson13 Note that 215 °C is pretty high if this is PLA, or low if this is e.g. PETG. Try to find out if it catches a ridge or something that prevents it to go to the nozzle. Can you find out where it stops? E.g. at the heat break, before the cold end, etc. E.g. does or doesn't it reach the nozzle?

Comment: The bed was indeed too high and clogged the nozzle. Thank you.